# Number of trials to observe all values of a uniform discrete random variable X with a probability of at least 1-q?

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable

> Let X take on p values with equal probability. If n trials are to be conducted to ensure that the probability of not observing any of these p values is less than or equal to q, what is the value of n?

Here's what I've been able to do so far -
Let $ X $ take on values $ 1, 2, ... p $. Let $ X_i $ denote the event that the value $ i $ is observed in the $ n $ trials. Then, we want

$ Pr(X_1^C \cup X_2^C \cup ... X_p^C) \leq q $

$ X_1^C \cup X_2^C \cup ... X_p^C = (X_1 X_2 ... X_p)^ C $, so we need $ Pr(X_1 X_2 ... X_p) \geq 1 - q $.

And one lower bound for this probability is

$ Pr(X_1 X_2 ... X_p) > \frac{{n-1 \choose p-1}}{p^n} $. Using this,

$ \frac{{n-1 \choose p-1}}{p^n} > 1 - q $

Not sure how to obtain the value of n from here. Are there other bounds/methods which make the calculation for $ n $ more conducive?

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector.